# Capybara-webkit and multitenancy using subdomain with default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a multi-tenant app that uses the request subdomain and default scope in the application controller. If I remove the `js: true` option on the test, it works perfectly. But with `js: true` it seems as though the `before_each` doesn't create the tennant before trying to execute the test.

Do I need to add a delay somehow? Any ideas?
Here is some stripped down code.

## Application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  prepend_around_filter :scope_current_store

  protected
    def current_store
      @store ||= Store.find_by(host: "#{request.subdomain}.#{request.domain}")
    end
    helper_method :current_store

    def scope_current_store
      Store.current_id = current_store.id
      yield
    ensure
      Store.current_id
    end
end
```

## spec_helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/webkit/matchers'
require 'rspec/retry'

Capybara.automatic_reload = true
Capybara.always_include_port = true
Capybara.app_host = "http://test.lvh.me"
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_unknown_urls
end

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f 
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.order = "random"
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.fail_fast = true

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    if driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    @store = create :store
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # config.include(Capybara::Webkit::RspecMatchers, :type => :feature)
end
```

## factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :store do
    name "Test Store"
    host "test.lvh.me"
    phone '9222'
  end
end
```

## Failing test that only visits a single link

```
it 'clicking a user displays their details', js: true do
  @user = create(:user)
  visit edit_admin_user_path(@user)
end
```

## The error is

```
  1) clicking a user displays their details
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31:in `scope_current_store'

Finished in 2.4 seconds (files took 0.25734 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Comment: Is the failing test in the features directory (or are you setting the :type metadata manually)?

Comment: Does the delay help you, just try and answer please